How to prevent GNOME terminal from catching the Super+² (twosuperior) keyboard shortcut?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with a French AZERTY keyboard, and the keyboard shortcut Super+² to "Switch windows of an application" (/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-group in dconf) doest NOT work in the GNOME terminal.

When I pressed the keystroke Super+² it prints the ² character instead of switching to other application windows with: ❌

GNOME terminal
GNOME text editor
Nautilus if the focus is in a text box (like the search box).

but it switches well to other application windows with: ✅

Google Chrome
PyCharm
Visual Studio Code

On the French AZERTY keyboard, the ² key is above the Tab key.

Question: Do you know how to prevent the GNOME terminal (and other apps) from capturing the keystroke Super+² with the french AZERTY keyboard?
PS: When I switch to the Engligh (US) QWERTY keyboard, the keystroke Super+` (key above Tab) does work in the GNOME terminal.
Workaround: The keystrokes Alt+² and Shift+Super+² work with the GNOME terminal.

Are you sure this behavior is specific to GNOME Terminal? With the setting of <Super>² I face the same problem in other apps as well, but with the default <Super>Above_Tab it works as expected even in GNOME Terminal. It's the window manager that decides whether to handle the keypress or forward it to the application, I don't think it can make this decision based on what the app wants.

Yes, I'm positive that if I switch to US QWERTY keyboard, I can use the <Super>(above tab) to switch between windows of a given application. I tested it successfully with GNOME terminal, Chrome, Visual Studio Code and Nautilus. Only with GNOME terminal + French AZERTY keyboard, the <Super>(above tab) doesn't work.

What is exactly the setting you see in dconf? And are you absolutely certain that that very setting, combined with a certain keyboard layout, doesn't work in GNOME Terminal but works in other apps (let's say multiple GEdit windows)?

I edit my main post to add the dconf default value. I discovered that as a workaround <Alt>Above_tab works in the GNOME terminal. I tested <Super>Above_Tab with the GNOME text editor, and I'm facing the same issue as with the GNOME terminal, i.e. when I press <Super>Above_Tab (² with the French keyboard), it prints the ² character instead of switching windows.

Thanks for the clarification. You've confirmed that, as I suspected, the issue is not related to GNOME Terminal in particular. It's about the windowing environment (GNOME Shell or similar) combined with international keyboard layouts. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this area and I can't help you any further, but I hope others will help you out here.
